# htaccess allow from 192.168.1.* isnt working

Tags: .htaccess

I made the following .htaccess Code, which typically should give access to the folder from internal network but external havent access. 
The Problem: with 192.168.1.* I get blocked, with 192.168.1.49 (my local IP) I have access.

Does anybody have a clue why the IP range is blocked, but specific IP is allowed and how to get this fixxed?

Thanks and Cheers

```
AuthUserFile /home/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.*
Satisfy any
```

Comment: try losing that star, like Allow from 192.168.1.

Comment: allright I tried so, but now you can get to the folder from external too. Without the point after 1 like Allow from 192.168.1 doesnt work either.

Comment: perhaps your external traffic also comes over a router with a local ip, using NAT? in that case you might have to exclude that routers ip.

Comment: it looks like the that! my phone got the ip .254. Hopefully last Question: how can i block this single specific IP? is there a possibility like deny,allow,deny?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/246003/apache-httpd-how-can-i-deny-from-all-allow-from-subnet-but-deny-from-ip-withi discusses that topic in detail

Answer (score 0):

## Block access to all visitors except yourself using entire network ip

```
order allow,deny
allow from 192.168.
deny from all
```

## It is also possible to block users by their host name.

```
order allow,deny
allow from stackoverflow.com
deny from all
```

## If you want to access with particular ip then use the following command,

```
order allow,deny
allow from 192.168.0.10
deny from all
```